# Correct way to set the properties of a JSON Schema Property to be the JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to write a schema for a JSON Schema document where I want one of the properties to be a JSON Schema document.

What I have so far is this (part of a larger schema doc), which I believe is wrong:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "description": "Describe request/response",
    "properties": {
        "requestSchema": {
            "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
        },
        "replySchema": {
            "$ref": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to say that the properties of the "requestSchema" object should be a JSON-Schema Object?

I've seen hyper schema mentioned but I'm not sure how this would be implemented in this case.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong? This should work just fine.

Comment: @Jason because when I validate with z-schema I get errors. I also tried different validators when I was also trying make additionalProperties:false with an allOf and I was getting errors? But maybe it's validator(s) error?

I also couldn't find an example of this use case - bad google-fu on my part :)

Comment: I haven't used z-schema, but the problem might be with configuring remote references. Every validator does this a little differntly. https://github.com/zaggino/z-schema#remote-references-and-schemas